# Occasional NPE occurs inside FirebaseAuth getCurrentUser

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase 12.0.1. Somewhat occasionally, but not *too* occasionally, one in 500-1000 users, my app experiences NPE while executing `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser`. I have attached a screenshot of the crash report at the bottom.

My `setupPage1` shown in the stack trace, is executing this line:

```
            val provdata = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.providerData
```

Is there some precaution I need to take before getting the user? The user is logged in to FA via the following before the above code runs

```
this.authMgr.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(this) { task: Task<AuthResult> ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    val user = task.result.user
                    user?.getIdToken(false)?.addOnCompleteListener { task: Task<GetTokenResult> ->
                        if (task.isSuccessful) {
                           ...stuff is done in here that leads to getCurrentUser
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the support response I received, this was a known issue and was fixed in v15.0.1. I have not upgraded yet to verify.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be certain without an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but my first guess is that this might be while Firebase is still determining if the user is signed in. You should always check *if* there is a current user:

```
val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
if (user != null) {
    val provdata = user!.providerData
    ...
}
```

Comment: But the crash occurs while `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser` is executing, not after. I've submitted a bug report via firebase support.